# How to send signed manifest to the PTE to interact with a published package

Tags: radix, scrypto

I managed to publish a package to the PTE via `resim publish`.

Now I am stuck as I have the following problem:

How to send a signed manifest to the PTE (from my account as I need a badge that will be returned)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Manifest, and sign it, you must back an element which upon activation constructs a Manifest, sends it to the PTE Extension to be signed, and receives the results.

Here is some sample code, this is the Typescript part:

```js
document.getElementById('instantiateMainComponent')!.onclick = async function () {
// Construct manifest
const manifest = new ManifestBuilder()
    // Instantiates component
    .callFunction(Package_Address, 'ComponentName', 'instantiate', [])
    // Deposits returned resources to account
    .callMethodWithAllResources(Account_Address, 'deposit_batch')
    .build()
    .toString();

  // Send manifest to extension for signing
  const receipt = await signTransaction(manifest);

// Add results here
}
```

And here is my associated HTML:

```html
<h2>3. Instantiate Main Component</h2>
<p><button id="instantiateMainComponent">Instantiate</button></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was one of the things I needed to do not too long ago. To clarify, for the public test environment (only the PTE, nothing else) not all transactions require signatures. Matter of fact, only transactions which withdraw funds from an account require a signature, nothing else requires one. This means the following:

1. For all transactions which do not withdraw funds from an account, you can continue using the PTE API to send your transactions and not sign them.
2. If signing transactions is necessary, then my recommendation is to construct and sign your transactions using Rust since it already has an SBOR implementation and you can very easily sign all of your transactions with Rust + the existing Scrypto libraries.

Regarding the Rust implementation, here is an example code I wrote in Rust which signs transactions and submits them to the PTE (PTE01 but you can change it to PTE02): https://github.com/0xOmarA/PTE-programmatic-interactions/blob/main/src/main.rs

Here is an example of this code being used in action: https://github.com/0xOmarA/RaDEX/tree/main/bootstrap